# Product Inequalites

Tags: inequality, intuition, products

I have the following Fraction:

> $ \frac{89*87*86}{49*47*46} $

and it is given that

**Upper**

1. > $ \frac{89*87*86}{49*47*46} > \frac{90*90*90}{50*50*50}  $

**Lower**

2. > $ \frac{89*87*86}{49*47*46} <= \frac{85*85*85}{45*45*45}  $

Could someone provide an Intuition on how to directly see that these inequalties hold (without using a calculator)?

For 1) it is easy to see that $ \frac{89*87*86}{49*47*46} > \frac{89*87*86}{50*50*50}  $ but  for the increase in the numerator I imagine one would have to make a general statement about the growth/decay of the two products given their elements. For example:  The relative difference of $(89*87*86)$ --> $(90*90*90)$ is smaller than $(49*47*46)$ --> $(50*50*50) $ so the fraction is decreasing.

Comment: By the [mediant inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)#Properties), for example inside the **Lower** inequality,

$$\frac 44 \le \frac{85}{45} \implies \frac 44 \le \frac{4+85}{4+45} \le \frac{85}{45}$$